# deprecation warning is getting while starting nodemon index.js in cli

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, mean-stack

getting an error like this[image]

i am doing a simple node js project that connect with mongodb. how to resolve this issue.?

this is the error getting in the terminal

```
DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
listening to serve 8080
Could not connect to database:  { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
```

mongo connect(index.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config/database');


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.uri, (err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log('Could not connect to database: ', err);
    }
    else{

        console.log('Connected to database: ' +config.db);
    }
});

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send('<h1>hello world</h1>');
  });

  app.listen(8080, ()=>{
      console.log('listening to serve 8080')
  });
```

database.js in config folder

```
const crypto = require('crypto').randomBytes(256).toString('hex');


   module.exports= {
        uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/' + this.db,
            secret:
        'crypto',
            db:
        'login'
    }
```

how to solve?

Comment: Please show your mongo connect function

Comment: plz check the question once more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mongoose.connect(config.uri, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log('Could not connect to database: ', err);
    }
    else{

        console.log('Connected to database: ' +config.db);
    }
});
```

That should work, just needs an extra parameter

Comment: in what way is it failing? oops. forgot a comma after the true}

Comment: i gave that coma. but still it is getting the error while i run nodemon index.js in terminal

Comment: events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Comment: deprecation error is gone, but there is an error [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: mongoose.connect(config.uri, {useNewUrlParser: true},(err) =>{
    if(err){
        console.log('Could not connect to database: ', err);
    }
    else{

        console.log('Connected to database: ' +config.db);
    }
});

Comment: That's the deprecation error fixed then, do CTRL-C in your console window and restart nodemon

Comment: events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event an  error like this is seen

Comment: potentially try adding a second param to your err function called data. Callbacks sometimes require 2

Comment: changing (err) => {} to (err,data) =>{}

Comment: [ts] 'data' is declared but its value is never read.
(parameter) data: any getting an error like this in editor

Comment: yes, but another error comes in terminal Could not connect to database:  { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

Comment: That error is unrelated to your code, that's the connection to your Database being wrong or your database refusing connection. Has it worked before?

Comment: Then yeah, double check if your ip and port is correct for your database is the only thing I can think of

Comment: where i need to check?

Comment: thankyou so much..i reinstalled mongoose, then it connected to db